# JavaBuilder handling CoreException

Tags: java, eclipse, virtual-machine, javabuilders, buildmanager

I am working with Eclipse. All was right during I was developing, but I have two days with some strange problems. I have a subproject with several packages. I want to use some classes between packages and Eclipse recognizes the imports. However, when I try to import, it shows that the import cannot be resolved. I saw the log file and I get the next lines:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File not found: E:\eclipse\PasarelaCARTIF\classes\es\cartif\zigbee\driver\Controller.class.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:55)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.openInputStream(LocalFile.java:371)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:702)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.getResourceContentsAsByteArray(Util.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.writeClassFileCheck(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:875)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.writeClassFileContents(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:817)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.writeClassFile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.acceptResult(AbstractImageBuilder.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:504)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:364)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.compile(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:321)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:301)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.build(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildDeltas(JavaBuilder.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:255)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:258)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:311)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:343)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:242)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

It is the first time it occurs. What is the problem?

Thanks a lot! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A long shot! Try clean in eclipse then build your projects. Starting with the project which have the class files needed later in the next compilation.

More than often eclipse messes up your project and you have to resort to strange methods such as the one described above. It's not unheard of to be forced to create a new workspace and import you project there and then it magically starts working again.

Look if your .java file from the project you have dependencies on really compiles to and creates a .class file at the desired folder indicated by the error message from the other project.

Answer (score 0):

*Another long shot:*

I think your hard drive may be crashing.
I've had the same experience, along with bad sectors crashing my VM, etc for the past few days. Thus, checking out a new workspace can be short term solution.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a Clean resolved this issue for me, but only after I physically deleted the `bin` directory first.